# Orphan Requirements in TFS

Tags: tfs

How can I make a query in TFS to say “Give me all the Project_A requirements that do not have any test cases linked to them”

I want to be able to easily look at what requirements have not been looked at by the test team and write/link test cases

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Work Items and Direct Links' type of query, e.g.

[image: work items with no test cases]